# Docker Error 2002 SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, mysql, docker, flask, sqlalchemy

Im currently working on a Flask Application with MySQL / SQLAlchemy.

I am trying to dockerize it but it is having some trouble connecting to one of the sockets. I've looked at nearly all the questions regarding this but I still get this error.

"sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)"

I am currently working on Mac and Mac's Terminal Program.

My Folder Tree is:
MainFolder -> .yml, db(folder), www(folder)

where db(folder) has a Dockerfile and www(folder) has the .py, requirements, and Dockerfile

Listed below is my code for this application.

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 
    www:
        build: www/.
        ports:
        - 5000:5000
        links:
        - db
        depends_on:
        - db

db:
    build: db/.
    volumes:
      - ./[database]:/usr/local/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: [password]
```

Dockerfile (for www)

```
FROM python:3-onbuild

# Place app in container
COPY . /opt/www
WORKDIR /opt/www

RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 5000
CMD python index.py
```

Dockerfile for (db)

```
# MySQL Container
FROM mysql:5.7.18

EXPOSE 3306
CMD ["mysqld"]
```

index.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)

# Configure your MySQL Connection
db = SQLAlchemy()
db_uri = 'mysql://root:password@localhost/[database]'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = db_uri
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db.init_app(app)

class Database(db.Model):

    versionID = db.Column('versionID', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    versionText = db.Column('versionText', db.String(500), 
    unique=False)

    def __init__(self, versionID, versionText):
        self.versionID = versionID
        self.versionText = versionText

    def serialize(self):
        return {
            'VersionID'     :   self.versionID,
            'VersionText'   :   self.versionText
        }

@app.route("/")
def test():
    return jsonify(json_list=[i.serialize for i in 
Database.query.all()])

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=5000)
```

My output should be in the browser in the form of JSON like this:

{ json_list = [
versionID: someID
versionText: someText
]
}

Something like that.

Any help is appreciated! Been trying to solve this for days!
Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), mysql is started with no database that can be used, unless you pass an environment variable.

Add this to the db section in your docker-compose file:

```
MYSQL_DATABASE: name-of-database
```

And the connection string should be:

```
'mysql://root:password@db/name-of-database'
```

Comment: I think your solution worked in avoiding the 2002 Error but now its throwing

1146, "Table '[database].database' doesn't exist"

Comment: You need to create the tables in the database by running `db.create_all()`

Comment: Even with the create all statement its throwing the 1146 error.

Much thanks though. Still new to docker so your answer helped me a bit!

Comment: Yeah this was the solution to my 2002 Error. I found the error i had on the DB missing part! Cheers!

Comment: What was causing the 1146 error? If you don't mind me asking.

Comment: Well my problem was I didnt successfully connect to the MySQL Container.

I ditched docker-compose and built a MySQL Container. Then when i initialized my FlaskApplication container i made sure to link it to the MySQL Container.

The problem with the 1146 error was that the FlaskContainer I had built using docker-compose didn't initialize a MySQL Database in that container. I was trying to connect to it locally but to do it you have to build a bridge between container and the local database in order for it to work - which i didnt do

Answer (score 0):

According to your docker-compose it something like this:

```
db_uri = 'mysql://root:password@db/[database]'
```

Comment: I dont quite understand what you are saying here.

Comment: Use "db" instead of "localhost" to connect to your database.

Comment: Now I am getting an unknown database '[database]'. Error code 1049.

Hmmm

Comment: According to [the documentation](https://hub.docker.com/_/mysql/), mysql automatically creates a new database using the same name of the container, in your case it'd be `db` so the string should be `'mysql://root:password@db/db'`

Comment: @LuisOrduz I see. I made the changes and its saying my Database is unknown. I run mysql in the terminal and 'show databases' and its there.

Those this mean Docker did not migrate my [database] over to the container?

Comment: What does show databases output? Is it the database called "db"?

Comment: @LuisOrduz mysql> show databases would output all the databases in MySQL in a table format 

Something like this

https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B4auNBJmtA52QlFGZVdoNFNzWFE

Comment: @LuisOrduz Hmm... I created a new Database called 'db' in my terminal and inserted some data in there. Still throws me the "Unknown Database" error.. Interesting.